# How to run a game in VirtualBox

Tags: windows, ubuntu, virtualbox

I use Ubuntu, and I want to play a Windows game, so I set up VirtualBox, and set up Windows XP SP3 in the VirtualBox.

But, when I try to run the game, it shows this:

```
This application cannot run under a Virtual Machine
```

So what can I do?

**updated:**

I found a link to deal with this question, but my english is not good,
so is this link useful enough? http://vmetc.com/2009/07/18/video-of-working-windows-directx-games-in-virtualbox-302-on-ubuntu-904/

Comment: Wow, the game actually checks for a virtual machine? That's something I haven't seen before.

Comment: Have you tried WINE?

Comment: i setup this game to wine , but it show many many many many errors ~~~~~~~

Comment: What's the game? There's often game-specific tutorials available for running on wine/virtualbox

Comment: The traditional answer from FLOSS advocates is to contact the game company and ask them to release a Linux version.

Comment: Without knowing what the game is I'm not completely sure we can help...

Comment: this game is a chinese game named 'qifan sanguozhengba' 起凡 三国争霸

Answer (score 2):

Probably nothing: if game checks for a virtual machine, you are lost.
Moreover: your vm doesn't have same GPU card of your pc nor (probably) full DirectX support, so you can't expect great performances...

Answer (score -2):

You can remove the virtual machine sign
open a notepad
type these:

@echo off

@reg copy HKLM\HARDWARE\ACPI\DSDT\VBOX__ HKLM\HARDWARE\ACPI\DSDT\NOBOX__ /s /f

@reg delete HKLM\HARDWARE\ACPI\DSDT\VBOX__ /f

@reg add HKLM\HARDWARE\DESCRIPTION\System /v SystemBiosVersion /t REG_MULTI_SZ /d "NOBOX   - 1" /f

@reg add HKLM\HARDWARE\DESCRIPTION\System /v VideoBiosVersion /t REG_MULTI_SZ /d "NOBOX   - 1" /f

@taskkill /f /im VBoxTray.exe

@exit

save it as .bat file
then run it as administrator

Comment: Please take a moment to properly format your answer.